# How to get SD card serial in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: drivers, 16.04, mount, sd-card

I'm using Ubuntu 16.04 and I'm trying to get serial number and `oemid` of SD card. I have found an instruction [here](http://www.cameramemoryspeed.com/sd-memory-card-faq/reading-sd-card-cid-serial-psn-internal-numbers/), but on my current system I cannot find it.

Previously I was using Ubuntu 15.10 and I'm pretty sure I was able to access proper place in `/sys/` to get this information, but now I cannot find it anymore.

After inserting a SD card it is automounted and I can access files on it, but `find /sys/ -name oemid` shows nothing.

Can you help me find out what is missing/why files in `/sys/` does not show up?

(I have Ubuntu 16.04 upgraded from 15.10)

Comment: If you go to gnome disks, you should see a field called `Device`.  What is the device name?  (Ex: `/dev/sdb`)

Comment: It is `/dev/sdb` and here I can see the serial number but I wanted to access it from the C application so I does not resolve my problem.

Comment: Ok, so you can get it from running the command `sudo udevadm info -a -n /dev/sdb`.

Comment: `udevadm info` works. Thank you. Do you have any idea what happend to the file in `sys` ?

Comment: Not sure.  It could be a change from 15.10 to 16.04, like you suggested.

Comment: It doesn't work on my computer either, running 16.04.  I found some documentation that said that the `sys` thing was only supposed to work on ARM, but that sounds rather unlikely to me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, find your device name. (`/dev/sdb`, `/dev/sdc`, etc.)

Then, run the following command:

```
sudo udevadm info -a -n /dev/xxx
```

...replacing xxx with the correct letters.

Comment: SD/microSD card can be `/dev/mmcblk0`.

Answer (score 2):

hdparm should be able to print the serial number

```
sudo hdparm -i /dev/sdb
```

Comment: I only get : `$ sudo hdparm -i /dev/sdb

/dev/sdb:
SG_IO: bad/missing sense data, sb[]:  70 00 05 00 00 00 00 0a 00 00 00 00 24 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
 HDIO_GET_IDENTITY failed: Invalid argument
`

Comment: It's a capital i.

Comment: either should work but not it seems for this device, not all sdcard readers make all the fields available.

Comment: On my system only in capital works.

Comment: small i is less verbose than capital I

Comment: Capital i also does not work for me :/

Comment: i am using version v9.48 of hdparm which is the standard one for ubuntu 16.04 , ive not seen any version of it fail when run with either of the -i options. I've used the small I for years without error.

Answer (score 1):

> To view the CID, the command is cat /sys/block/mmcblk0/device/cid (the
> exact location may be different)

> This will not work through a USB card reader because the command to
> retrieve the card information is intercepted and not understood by
> card readers. Not all computers with built-in card slots will work,
> some internal card readers are connected through a USB bus.

Source: https://www.cameramemoryspeed.com/sd-memory-card-faq/reading-sd-card-cid-serial-psn-internal-numbers/